# django phileo like app template problems

Tags: python, django, django-templates, reusability

I am trying in use the django phileo(liking app) on my project but I keep running into template "TemplateSyntaxError" errors. 
example: `TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'phileo_css'`

What I'm doing is inserting `{% phileo_css %}` in my header tags within my base.html. I extends this base.html in another html file but then I keep running into this error. I really dont know how to fix this. Can anyone provide any clues as to what I'm doing wrong

Edit:
This is my header file for my base.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load phileo_tags %}
{% load comments %}
{% load pagination_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% phileo_css %}
    {% phileo_js %}
</head>
.......
```

As you can see in the above code, I have loaded all my tags. After loading the `phileo_tags`
I insert `{% phileo_css %}` in the header tags just like the docs stated `http://readthedocs.org/docs/phileo/en/latest/usage.html` and still I am getting the same error. Could I still be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. I was using `version 0.2` of the app. I upgraded to `version 0.3.dev1` and my problem was solved. Thanks to "linux-warrior" for pointing out that the version could be a problem.

It is important to note that `pip install -U phileo` does not install the latest version. So instead I downloaded the project off github and placed it in my python path and then ran `python setup.py install` and everything worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add {% load phileo_tags %} at the top of your base.html.

Comment: Hey linux-warrior, I've updated my question providing some code of how I'm loading my tags, however I still get the same error. any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you also have "django.contrib.staticfiles" enabled and STATIC_URL set to something?

Comment: Please also check the version of phileo you are using. The 0.1 version didn't have phileo_css and phileo_js tags, you need to install the development one for them.

Comment: Yes I have django.contrib.staticfiles and STATIC_URL='/static/' enabled. I am also using version 0.2. I Think I will upgrade and see if that makes a difference.